# Running individual commands works but not when combines in a shell script.. Why?

Tags: shell, mount

I need to run the following set of commands in a shell script

```
modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 path/to/image/file
sudo mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt/temp
python copyFiles.py
sudo umount /mnt/temp
sudo qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
sudo rmmod nbd
```

When I individually run these commands it works fine, but when I put them in a shell script and executed that shell script, I always end up with an error in the `mount` command.

So I threw in a `sleep 1` before `mount` and it works as expected.

What could be the reason behind this?
(Some sort of asynchronous call registration delay/ race condition?)

Comment: What error do you get from `mount`?

Comment: mount error: mount point `/mnt/temp` does not exist

Comment: I do not know what the qemu-nbd command does but just checking - Is /mnt/temp by any chance created by the qemu-nbd command ?

Comment: No, it isn't. I have to manually create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mount error: mount point /mnt/temp does not exist

So it seems the directory `/mnt/temp` doesn't exist when you are running it as a shell script. Just create it or add this in your script somewhere before the mount command:

```
mkdir /mnt/temp 2>&1 /dev/null
```

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge not according to `mount`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error. I will comment/update asap

Answer (score 0):

Both mount and the previous command require escalated privileges. Does it error cause the lock is still in place from the previous command when mount tries to run?

Comment: What *lock* are you referring to? How would I check this?